# How to hookup a UITableview when it is part of of a UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, datasource

I have a UIViewController that has a UITableView sitting on a UIView that is hidden. I have created a data view object and implmented the data methods and hooked it up in the Interfaced builder as a datasource. I can get the table to show but not populate. I have tried creating a  UITableViewControler and adding that the the UIViewController and that did not work. 
What am I missing?

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions to show some appreciation to the people that has given you free advice

Comment: You should really accept some answers to your questions. If you don't, people will downvote your questions and stop answering them. To accept an answer, press the ✔ next to the question that you think helped you the most. It will reward you by giving you +2 reputation, and the author of your accepted answer with +10 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If your connections are good, maybe the tableview loads before the data is there.  Try

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

If that doesn't work, you have bad connections.  You can always set the delegate and datasource outside IB.

```
[tableView setDelegate:uitableviewdelegate]  
[tableView setDataSource:uitableviewdatasource]
```